Difference between metric and intrinsic metric
I am studying metric spaces $(X, d)$ and the corresponding intrinsic metric of that space, say $d_I \colon X \times X \to \mathbb{R}_\geq \cup \{ \infty \}$. That is, $d_I(x, y)$ is the infimum over the arc length of all curves connecting $x$ and $y$. Clearly, $d_I \geq d$. However, I am interested in the properties of the difference between the two, i.e., $\bar{d} = d_I - d$.
Are there some general statements we can make about $\bar{b}$? For instance, we know that it is nonnegative, but it is not a metric itself since it does not satisfy the triangle inequality.
Note: I am actually interested in the setting where $d$ is an asymmetric metric, but for starters knowing the properties of $\bar{d}$ for metrics is sufficient.
